# How to convert List<Object> into List<List<String>> using Java 8 Stream

Tags: stream

Here is what I have:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
List<DataRow> dataRowList = new ArrayList<>();

DataRow dataRow1 = new DataRow("Ginger Rogers", "Dance Unlimited", "Broadway 23");
DataRow dataRow2 = new DataRow("Fred Astaire", "Rainbow-United", "Wall Street 3");

dataRowList.add(dataRow1);
dataRowList.add(dataRow2);


listOfLists = dataRowList.stream()
            .map(this::buildList)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


private List<String> buildList(DataRow dataRow) {
    String str = dataRow.getName() + "," + dataRow.getOrganization() + "," + dataRow.getAddress();
    return Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
}
```

I would like to convert dataRowList into ----> listOfLists using Java 8 Stream.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Yes, `private List<String> buildList(DataRow dataRow) {
    return List.of(dataRow.getName(), dataRow.getOrganization(), dataRow.getAddress());
}` (java>=9, list immutable;)

Comment: Thank you.  Good suggestion.  Forgot about the List.of in Java 9.